# Can the uniform bounds for the elements in a positive matrix's m power be predicted a priori?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My question is that: If all the elements $a_{i,j}$ of a positive matrix $A (A=[a_{i,j}])$ are uniform bounded, that is, $$0<\underline{a}\leq a^{i,j} \leq \overline{a},$$
can we predict the positive scalars $\underline{\beta}$ and $\overline{\beta}$ such that all the elements of the positive matrix's $m$-th power $(A^m=[a_m^{i,j}] )$ are uniformly bounded as well. Mathematically speaking, $$0<\underline{\beta}\leq a_m^{i,j} \leq \overline{\beta}$$
If it does, what's relation between $\underline{a}$ and $\underline{\beta}$, $\overline{a}$ and $\overline{\beta}$?

Comment: A matrix has finitely many elements and so it would appear that $a_{i,j}$ is always bounded by the maximum entry.

Comment: If you want to find a bound independent on the exponent $m$, then this cannot be done (for example, you can take a positive matrix which is "near to" twice the identity matrix, and see what happens).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the maximum entry of $M$ is $a_{i_0,j_0}=A$, then we can bound the largest entry of $M^m$ by $n^{m-1}A^m$ where $n$ is the side length of the matrix. This comes out of the fact that each entry of $M^n$ is less than each entry of the matrix comprised only of $A$'s raised to the $m$. In such a matrix, each element is given by $A\cdot A+\cdots + A\cdot A$, and then iterating. It's pretty clear this bound is optimal, and cannot be made independent of $m$. In your notation, $\overline{\beta}=n^{m-1}\overline{a}^m$.

The same argument works for lower bounds, since every entry is positive. This gives $\underline{\beta}=n^{m-1}\underline{a}^m$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, does that mean, in my question's setting, the upper bound is $\overline{\beta}=n^{m-1}\overline{a}^m$, and the lower bound is $\underline{\beta}=n^{m-1}\underline{a}^m$?

Comment: Yup! I'll add that explicitly.